# Some columns returned empty from interbase sql

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, interbase

I have strange problem on my pc/server.

I run query such as

Select field1, fieldId from myTable

this will return in average 10 results

**Now the strange thing:**
sometimes when i render it to my drop down list, the fieldId is blank, i mean rendered blank, with text and sometimes the field1 is blank.

When i have checked for the data, the data are always present.

Any idea how to solve this?

We are using an Interbase XE server on Windows Server 2008 R2. We are accessing it through the ODBC driver (installed on the server) which came with Interbase.

I execute the query fiew times and from this sometimes i have data from one column missing.

Any suggestion is welcome

PS this i cannot reproduce this error, it just happens

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Comment: @ZippyV - >i do not believe that the code is an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
just heard from support

On rare occasions, I've seen the same on Windows 7. I'll assume Windows
2008 has the same issue. I've only know one other customer to experience
this problem, so it's a problem pretty much on the back burner. Please
create a support case by going to http://support.embarcadero.com, then
click the Create a Case button and say you need to assistance with
installing your product. Reply with the case number here and I'll make
sure you are taken care of.

Hope this helps to your all too, if you experiencing the same problem

Comment: The DataDirect ODBC Interbase driver has pathological issues (nulls returned and random access violations) when running on Windows 2008, Vista or 7. The EasySoft ODBC Interbase driver exhibits some of the same issues too. We moved to IBProvider which works perfectly so far.

Comment: In short go away from interbase if you can.